# Adding pod nodeSelector after creation

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

Using OpenShift 3.1/K8 1.1 and given a pod that has already been created with/without a `nodeSelector`.
I.e.

```
apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    generateName: blah-
    labels:
      name: blah
  spec:
    containers:
        image: some/image
        name: blah-image
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
    nodeSelector: # can you add this after this pod has been created?
      region: infra
```

Is it possible to change/add a `nodeSelector`?

Similar to the way you add/modify [labels](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it in the associated ReplicationController (if any) but not in the definition of a running Pod. If you edit the RC as suggested the Pod itself **must** be recreated in order to start on the selected node(s).

Answer (score 1):

In OpenShift if you are using a deployment config (the predecessor to Kube's Deployment object) you can edit your DC and add them.  On the cli it's:

```
oc edit dc/NAME
```

That will trigger a rolling update that creates a new RC and scales down the old, unlabeled pods.